# How can i modify this function by not using same d for 31 times?

Tags: sql-server

I have 31 days in a table as `d1` to `d31`.
I'm getting `id` from another table and using it in a `WHERE` clause
and I need to check in `d1`-`d31` which columns have x or y char present in SQL Server.

This is a function I'm trying.

How can I optimise this from `IN` to `IF` and not using `dXX` 31 times?

```
declare @delete as bit
set @delete=0
if exists(select * from tblname where id=@id and(d1 in('x','y') or D2 in('x','y')....,D31 in('x','y'))
return @delete 
else 
set @delete =1
return @delete
```

Comment: mysql or (ms) sql-server? please remove unrelated tags

Comment: Schema seems like a bad choice. I'd have day as a column and have it's value be 1-31. Is `return 0` part of the query or from a different script/code block?

Comment: The definition of the function isn't complete either. Include the whole DDL statement

Comment: @user3783243 i have updated total function . pls check

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN id = @id AND D1IN ('x','y')
      THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS Thing
FROM (
  SELECT D1 AS d FROM Somewhere
  UNION
  SELECT D2 FROM Somewhere
  ...
  UNION
  SELECT D31 FROM Somewhere
) T
```

It is the nature of SQL that you have to write out all of the column names.
If this is a problem then it's probably a problem with your schema being unsuited for the queries you want to write against it.

You could bodge it up by doing something like

```
CREATE VIEW D
AS
  SELECT 1 AS D, D1 AS Value FROM Somewhere
  UNION
  ...
  UNION
  SELECT 31 AS D, D31 As Value FROM Somewhere
```

Comment: i have updated the code above please check once and thanks for this